# How to delete and add an li element inside a ul tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, addition

I had the below html code

```
<ul class="sales_details clearfix">
    <li class="blue_disc">
        <a id="product_detail" href="">Som stuff</a> 
        <span id="product_revenue">$45</span> 
   </li>
</ul>
<input  class="update" type="button">
```

And  my `jquery` code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.update').click(function() {
        var array_list = response_list; // I will get response_list from somewhere as list of dictionaries
        $.each(array_list, function (i, item) {
            href = "/products/" + item.products__id + "/"
            $('#product_detail').attr('href', href).html(item.products__name);
            $('#product_revenue').html(item.revenue);
        });
    });
});
```

So when from my above html and jquery code, the `li element` with class `blue_disc` is updating, but the values are overriding and as a result I can able to see only one record as `li`

For example I have the `array_list` as below:

```
[{'products__name':'One', 'revenue':'45'},
{'products__name':'two', 'revenue':'32'},
{'products__name':'three', 'revenue':'35'}]
```

I can able to see only one `li` element with `product__name : three` data,

so what I want to do is

1. First delete the `li element` with class `blue_disc`(Because by default i am displaying some data)
2. The create an li element like with the details above,

So how to

1. Delete an `li element` with a class
2. How to update an element exact after the `ul` with class `sales_details` as above ?

Comment: This code cannot possibly be doing anything useful. `$('.update').click(){` should be `$('.update').click(function(){`, no?

Comment: sorry my bad.... a typo ...., but i need to implement the functionality like above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your `click` syntax is wrong. Secondly, you're updating the attributes of the existing element, not creating any new ones in the loop. Try this:

```
$('.update').click(function () {
    $('.sales_details').empty();

    var array_list = response_list;
    $.each(array_list, function (i, item) {
        var $li = $('<li />').appendTo('.sales_details');

        $('<a />', {
            'href': "/products/" + item.products__id + "/",
            'text': item.products__name
        }).appendTo($li);

        $('<span />', {
            'text': '$' + item.revenue
        }).appendTo($li);
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/tG5rT/2/)

Answer (score 0):

First off, your HTML needs changing. If you want to have multiple `li`s, then you can't have elements inside them with the same `id`. That makes for an invalid DOM and all kinds of headaches.

To answer your questions:

To remove all elements with a particular class, do `$('li.blue_disc').remove()`.

To create the new elements and append them to the `ul`, do something like this...

```
$('.update').click(function() {
    // remove the current li.blue_disc elements
    $('li.blue_disc').remove();

    $.each(array_list, function (i, item) {
        // create the li
        var li = $('<li class="blue_disc"/>'); 

        // add the link
        li.append('<a class="product_detail" href="' + 
                  item.products__id +
                  '">Som stuff</a>'
        );

        // add the span
        li.append('<span class="product_revenue">$' +
                  item.revenue +
                  '</span>'
        );

        // add the li to the ul
        $('.sales_details').append(li);
    });
});
```